# Why does HttpWebrequest through .Net proxy fail?

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I have the following code:

```
int repeat = 1;
int proxyIndex = 1;
if (listBox1.Items.Count == proxyIndex) //If we're at the end of the proxy list
{
  proxyIndex = 0; //Make the selected item the first item in the list
}
try
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
    string proxy = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    string[] proxyArray = proxy.Split(':');
    WebProxy proxyz = new WebProxy(proxyArray[0], int.Parse(proxyArray[1]));
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    {
      repeat++;
      continue;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) //Incase some exception happens
  {
    listBox2.Items.Add("Error:" + ex.Message);
  }
```

I don't understand what I do wrong?

Comment: It would help if you told us what it IS or ISN'T doing

Comment: Basically, the feature of the program is; the user can load a proxy list into a list box, it will then browse a link specified in a text box; move onto the next proxy browse the page then move on etc.. 
It isn't browsing the page..

Comment: Lawrence, I tried to reformat your code (basically trying to get the indenting consistent to make it more readable), but from what I could tell there was something wrong with it -- the try and catch blocks don't seem to match up.  Could you double-check whether you have all the braces etc. that are in your actual program?

Comment: Yeah, all the braces match up.. I'm not sure what's wrong :(

Comment: OBTW, there's no such thing as a C# proxy. You meant a .NET proxy.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but you really should not catch all exceptions and stuff their messages in a list box. A list box filled with 'Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object' is not exactly good error handling. I had a lot to say about this in a previous life: http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/06/14/631923.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting Proxy on your HttpWebRequest.  (You're creating a WebProxy object, but not using it.)  You need to add:

```
request.Proxy = proxyz;
```

before calling request.GetResponse().

Answer (score 1):

You also need to fix your use of objects which implement `IDisposable`. Since they're created in a loop, you cannot delay this - it could be causing any amount of random damage:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    string[] proxyArray = proxyHostAndPort.Split(':');
    WebProxy proxyz = new WebProxy(proxyArray[0], int.Parse(proxyArray[1]));
    request.Proxy = proxyz;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```